# more elegant way to calculate center of polygon if I already have center of similar polygon

Tags: javascript, math, matrix

So I have an array of polygons and need to get the center of each one, they are all the same polygon positioned at different places. The polygons look like the following

```
[[1100,173.2050807567],[1100,86.60254037829999],[1137.5,108.25317547289998],[1175,129.9038105675]]
```

So I am currently doing the following

```
polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
     const polygonX = getX(polygon);
     const polygonY = getY(polygon);
     const xmin = Math.min( ...polygonX );
     const xmax = Math.max( ...polygonX );
     const ymin = Math.min( ...polygonY );
     const ymax = Math.max( ...polygonY );
     const dx = (xmin+xmax) / 2;
     const dy = (ymin+ymax) / 2;
```

so dx and dy gives me the center. However I have to think there is a transformation matrix possible if I have the center of the first one because they are all the same shape, is there a transformation matrix function I can use to get the center of polygon[1] if I have already figured out the center of polygon[0]

so I could do something like

```
const firstPolygon = polygons[0];
const polygonX = getX(firstPolygon);
const polygonY = getY(firstPolygon);
const xmin = Math.min( ...polygonX );
const xmax = Math.max( ...polygonX );
const ymin = Math.min( ...polygonY );
const ymax = Math.max( ...polygonY );
const dx = (xmin+xmax) / 2;
const dy = (ymin+ymax) / 2;

polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
  const center = transformMatrixFunction([dx, dy], polygon);
```

Obviously the function can be structured however is wanted, the above is just a silly example, anyways I suppose the first parameter would not be [dx, dy] but would require some zeros in there somewhere.

Comment: If they are all the same size/shape, could you just find the centre relative to one of the points and apply that relative position to the same point in each shape?

Comment: @DBS I guess if I was using CSS or the DOM because then I would have relative positioning but this is a drawing api.

Comment: Sorry, I think I worded that poorly, what I meant was that you could work out the distance between a specific point of the shape (e.g. the first point) and your calculated centre. So, the centre could be `x+4, y+3` relative to that point, then you would just apply that same distance to the first point of each shape to get the centre. It's just a way to only do the complex calculation once.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense I Will try that.

Comment: although I guess that means I still have to calculate at least the minx and miny to add the centerXdiff and centerYdiff to.